# unwrap() on a fs::read_to_string leads to Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in Android

Tags: android, rust

Thanks for your kind help in advance!

I'm trying to use a rust library to work on database file in an Android app. I'm not quite sure yet which method might be the best here. My best try so far was with fs:write & fs:read_to_string. I tried several paths including the context.getFilesDir()
 from Java with no succcess. When I try checking on the results of them I discovered that unwrap() and expect() will lead to such an error:

```
2019-12-24 00:38:54.652 10459-10459/com.example.android A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 10459 (example.android), pid 10459 (example.android)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static native String hello(final String to);
    private static native String getTitle(final String webcontent);
    private static native boolean buildDatabase(final String webcontent);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Load rust library
        System.loadLibrary("rust");
        Log.d("Rust", this.hello("IMPP"));

        String r = this.hello("Android_11");

        // Download google sheet
        Downloader task = new Downloader();
        String result = null;

        try {
            result = task.execute("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTZMOCrZdhsWPB4O-YiLrfE_sR2DcU3hgHQyg1y-_R648YOP3uX9eb0-gAqJN4Re70swEOONzS5t-Yc/pubhtml").get();

            //Log.i("Content", result);

            largeLog("Content", result);


            r = this.getTitle(result);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText(r);


    }

    public static void largeLog(String tag, String content) {
        if (content.length() > 1000) {
            Log.d(tag, content.substring(0, 1000));
            largeLog(tag, content.substring(1000));
        } else {
            Log.d(tag, content);
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies] 
jni = { version = "0.10.2", default-features = false }
}

[profile.release]
lto = true

[lib]
name = "rust"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

lib.rs

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
mod lib_impp;

use jni::objects::{JObject, JString};
use jni::sys::jstring;
use jni::JNIEnv;
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

// Return Part of Java String
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_getTitle(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JObject,
    j_recipient: JString,
) -> jstring {
    // convert JString to CString and append it to our JNIEnv
    env.new_string(lib_impp::create_db(
        CString::from(CStr::from_ptr(
            env.get_string(j_recipient).unwrap().as_ptr(),
        ))
        .to_str()
        .unwrap()
        .to_string(),
    ))
    .unwrap()
    .into_inner()
}
```

lib_impp.rs
    use std::fs;

```
pub fn create_db(input: String) -> String {
    let data = input + "Extra String";
    let result = fs::write("test.json", data);
    let file = fs::read_to_string("test.json");
    return file.unwrap(); // This will result in a Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)
    // return String::from("test"); // This will return "test"
}
```

Comment: From what I can see you should be able to write `CString::from(*env.get_string(j_recipient).unwrap()))` because of the `Deref` implementations, and avoid using `CStr::from_ptr`. I think the pointer you are passing it might not live long enough. (It's the only actually unsafe function AFAICT)

Comment: But this begs the question: why did you make your function `unsafe`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Yes, that seems to be the only unsafe function. But replacing it the way you recommended results in:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<jni::wrapper::strings::ffi_str::JNIStr>` is not implemented for `std::ffi::CString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself. Turns out that the path that I used was incorrect. I used getFilesDir() in Java to send me the files directory and in this path i was succesful at writing and reading.